# Aggregating Data between the occurrence of two events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this:

| Date | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | Load | 40.00 |
| 1/2/21 | Spend | -20.00 |
| 1/3/21 | Withdraw | -10.00 |
| 1/4/21 | Load | 40.00 |
| 1/5/21 | Spend | -20.00 |
| 1/5/21 | Spend | -15.00 |
| 1/6/21 | Load | 40.00 |

What I would like to do is get some output like this:

| Load Date | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | Spend | -20.00 |
| 1/1/21 | Withdraw | -10.00 |
| 1/4/21 | Spend | -35.00 |

I want to aggregate the amount of money allocated to each transaction **type** between two rows that were of **load** types.

How would I do this in SQL?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? (Why is this also tagged vertica?)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can create a cumulative count of load and then aggregate:

```
select min(load_date), type, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 'load' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by load_date) as load_grp
      from t
     ) t
where type <> 'load'
group by load_grp;
```

That said, your results look more like aggregated by date and type for non-load events:

```
select load_date, type, sum(amount)
from t
where type <> 'load'
group by load_date, type;
```

Comment: Thank you! The idea of having a cumulative count of load was very helpful. Using this as an identifier of which transaction type belongs to a specific load allowed me to aggregate as needed!